# How to locate the OpenAPI specification for Guidewire InsuranceNow cloud API?

Tags: openapi, guidewire

We are unable to locate the OpenAPI specification for Guidewire InsuranceNow cloud API. Could someone kindly provide guidance on where and how we can access the OpenAPI specification for InsuranceNow?

Comment: https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/in/20233/apiref/generated/InsuranceNow%20API/Addresses/addresses-countries--get